# Java NIO: Read data from Channel which does not contain any data. How do I handle this situation?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, socketchannel

Java code below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(
                "google.com", 80));

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

        while ((channel.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            buffer.clear();
        }

        channel.close();
    }
}
```

This code is easy.

But I did not write any data to Channel, so, it does not contain any data to reading.

In this case method `channel.read()` performed **too long** and do not return any data.

How do I handle this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a blocking method. What did you expect?

You can set a read timeout on the underlying socket, or you can put the channel into non-blocking mode, probably in conjunction with a Selector.

Comment: could you please explain, what mean "blocking method"?

Comment: @user471011 I mean exactly what it says in the Javadoc. In blocking mode, it will block until at least one byte of data arrives or an end of stream.

Answer (score 5):

***Update:*** Looking at your example you are connecting to a web server. The web server will not respond till you tell it what you want to do. For example doing a `GET` request.

Example (no proper character encoding):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open(
            new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80));

    channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes()));

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    while ((channel.read(buffer)) != -1) {

        buffer.flip();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.limit()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        System.out.print(new String(bytes));

        buffer.clear();
    }

    channel.close();
}
```

---

If you don't want your `read`s to be blocking you would need to [configure your channel as non-blocking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#configureBlocking%28boolean%29). Otherwise it will sit and wait till data is available. You can read more about non-blocking NIO [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/10/02/javanio.html?page=4).

```
channel.configureBlocking(false);
```